# Valid OAuth redirect URIs not able to add localhost in Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am testing with login with Facebook in localhost, so I tried to add my localhost in Facebook's app page https://developers.facebook.com/apps/appid/fb-login/settings/

```
Valid OAuth redirect URIs
```

The URL I am adding is

```
http://localhost/sugumar/facebooklogin/
```

after inputting I am clicking on save changes but it's not saved, it shows only the URLs previously stored.

I have already two URLs added in  Valid OAuth redirect URIs.

My goal is to test https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted for signing in functionality in localhost before uploading it to the server.

Comment: Works fine for me. Do you get any error messages after clicking Save Changes? Do the other settings (App Domains, set up platforms) also contain localhost?

Comment: @CBroe No error message bro, It showed so many errors for other things ,for normal login itself, it showed "please close the browser and and reopen", and it didn't allow me to create a new app. I cleared cache in the browser, but it didn't help, then I restarted my system.. Now it works fine.. but I don't know what caused the problem

Answer (score 3):

I discovered that a secure connection is required, so if you change http to https, or just remove http all together and allow it to autofill with https, you can save the changes.

Comment: Thank you! This should be noted in the docs...